# Methods belonging to multiple classes

Tags: c++, oop

I am making a small project as an extension of a larger body of work.  As part of this larger project there is a class which contains a number of methods.
I would like to use some of these methods as methods in my new class but I feel like there must be a better way than simply duplicating the code with a different class name!
Is there a way to make a method belong to multiple classes (I should mention all of this is c++)!
Cheers,
Jack

Comment: Can't you just use the class in the other part of the code? it's the principle of OOP. If that class has some heavy-weight members then you should separate data and control logic

Comment: Have you ever looked at traits? http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442

Comment: Why don't you use just Subtyping? The common methods you can put in Parent class.

Answer (score 3):

There are roughly speaking two possibilities:

- inheritance: only if your new class (B) and the class you're interested in (A) really represent *is a* relationship.
- composition: add the class you're interested in (A) as a field in your new class (B). You can then easily use its methods.

If class A has more methods than you need, then most probably it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single%5fresponsibility%5fprinciple), and you should split it. If B will have methods with the same name as A, then consider also introducing an interface with methods common to both classes (in general this+composition seems a better solution than inheritance).

Comment: +1 for splitting or known as *refactoring*.

Answer (score 0):

One method can not be a part of more than one class other than inheritance. What you can do is to make a global function lets say `void func1()` and a local function lets say `void func2()` in each of the classes. In the code of the func2() just simply call the func1() which is the global function. This way you won't have to write the same code multiple times